# How can I create my own JMSTemplate?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am new to JMS and MQ. As I know in order to be able to read messages from IBM MQ through JMS, messages have to have JMS header. I don't have a chance to add JMS header. Therefore, I want to create some sort of MQTemplate that also supports transactionality of messages through Sessions just like JMS. Does anyone know best example of how I can achieve it. Thank you!

Comment: But you're not supposed to do that yourself. You're supposed to use an existing JMS client library (or bypass JMS and go straight to native MQ as IBM suggests, but of course they'd suggest that).

Comment: Your application doesn't need to worry about a JMS header. You can use the JMS API to receive  any message from an MQ queue or subscription, irrespective of whether the message was sent by another JMS application or one of the other APIs that MQ supports. Have you tried this and failed?